# Magento 2: Default mode not merged css

Tags: magento2.2.4, merge-css

I enabled Default Store mode and merge css enabled after that, I have run all the commands from command line but still css not merged. Any one help me?

```
Magento Version:2.2.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any specific reason why you are trying to merging CSS in default mode ?!!

I think if site development is completed then you should move to the production mode not even developer or default.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

I recently face same issue after digging found that by mistake there's one CSS which going to 404.

After fixing this I can able to do merge css.

Hope it will help you.